# How to make compiler parse `a[b]` with python-PLY?

Tags: python, compiler-construction, ply

PLY's document: https://ply.readthedocs.io/_/downloads/en/latest/pdf/

I try to make it parse `a[b]`:

```py
precedence = (
        # other rules...
        ('left', 'AND'),
        # other rules...
        ('nonassoc', 'GET-ITEM'),
    )

def p_expression(p):
    """
    expression : expression AND expression
               | expression '[' expression ']' %prec GET-ITEM
               | other rules...
    """
```

But something bad happening, when I have this token stream, it do not make thing that I want:

```
expression AND expression '[' expression ']'
```

It do not shift token `'['` but reduce `expresion -> expression AND expression`.

It make me sad and I go to read the document. Now I know that it do not shift `'['` because token `'['` do not have high precedence... Wait but why? I have used `%prec GET-ITEM`!

To be honest, I do not know how `%prec` works (I only find two paragraphs in document)... Is it just change the first token's precedence? And how can I make it? Is it the only way that just make `'['` have high precedence - but even `'['` is not a operator?

Thx.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30339317/1566221

Comment: Hello, @rici , thanks for your kindly answer. I learn a lot. So the answer is that it is the only way that set the token `'['` as a high precedence, isn't it?

Comment: So, the `%prec` only work for reduce, right?

Comment: effectively. But `%prec` is only rarely necessary. It's needed for unary `-` because `-` has two meanings, but that's not the case here, for example. Also, in this case the reduction of `a[b]` is unambiguous.

Comment: @rici , yes. I think I really get it. I only need to set `'['`'s precedence but not `%prec`.